# Does nodetool import use the same underlying SSTable?

Tags: cassandra

I want to have a `temp` keyspace, which is a copy of a snapshot of one of the current keyspaces, e.g. `users_ks`. I took the snapshot of the `users_ks` as:

```
nodetool snapshot -t temp_table_snapshot -- users_ks
```

After creating the `temp` keyspace, I import the snapshot

```
nodetool import users_frozen <TABLE> /etc/cassandra/data/users_ks/<TABLE>-<hash>/snapshots/temp_table_snapshot
```

And I found that, when I run `nodetool status`, the `Load` size of the data doesn't changed. Does this mean the `import` doesn't create new data from the snapshot and reuse the underlying SSTables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodetool import` command will load the SSTables and copy them to the corresponding directory of the target `ks_name.table_name`.

If the underlying schema of the destination table is not identical or compatible, the `import` operation will fail.

You need to review the `system.log` on the node for clues to see if there was an issue importing the data. Without knowing the underlying issue, it is impossible to determine what happened. Cheers!